# Why does -7 return True in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

Basically this question is pertraining to a [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/cje5yh/short_python_challenge_make_this_return_true/). The function shouldn't be returning True mathematically. But -7 as mentioned in the comment's return's True surprisingly. Can anyone explain why -7 specifically?  I'm using python 3.7.

```
def check(x):
    if 1+x is x+1:
        return False
    if 2+x is not x+2:
        return False
    return True

check(-7)
True
```

Comment: Python allocates integer in following way: 
https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/

So basically, every python program has allocated integers from -7 to 257
```
#define NSMALLPOSINTS           257
#define NSMALLNEGINTS           5
```

Since `is` operator checks reference to objects, then you can do trick like:
```python
>>>a = 1
>>>b = 1
>>>a is b
True
>>>a = 300
>>>b = 300
>>>a is b
False
```

In order to make your function correct you should use `==` instead of `is`.

Comment: The answer is also well explained in reddit.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I agree. SO is more popular in terms of programming questions. So keeping it here so more people can see and learn something more.

Comment: @BharathM great point !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `is` operator checks for ***identity***, not for equality:

```
In [670]: id(-6), id(-6)
Out[670]: (9830796528, 4454912496)

In [671]: -6 == -6
Out[671]: True
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: Well, if you pass -6 to the function, it wont return True.

Comment: @BharathM see the dupe, the key detail is that Cpython caches integers between -5 and 256